# JQueryUI Dialog won't open

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a very basic form to act as a modal dialog and a button. Here is my code snippet:

```
this.element.find('.column-chooser').dialog({
    'autoOpen':false,
    'modal':true,
    'height':300,
    'width':300
});

this.element.find('.choose-cols').button().on('click', function () {
    this.element.find('.column-chooser').dialog('open');
    alert('Hello, world!');
}.bind(this));
```

(The reason I'm using 'this.element.find' rather than "$" is because this is a prototype object that is applied dynamically).

As of now, If I set 'autoOpen:true' instead of false, the dialog box shows just fine. Clicking my button with the 'choose-cols' class does pop up my "Hello, World!" alert box, but it does not open the dialog box. Also, this snippet:

```
this.element.find('.column-chooser').dialog('open');
```

inserted directly after the dialog definition also does not open the dialog box. It's almost as if my JS is completely ignoring the 'open' command. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
this.element.find('.choose-cols').button().live('click', function () {
this.element.find('.column-chooser').dialog('open');
alert('Hello, world!');
```

}.bind(this));

As i know for dynamically added objects ON doesn't work properly. Try using LIVE instead of ON.

Comment: Tried .live() and it just broke the rest of the JS. Also, though, I don't think it's the click event that's having the issue. The alert('Hello, world!') triggers just fine, but the dialog doesn't open. Thanks!